# Which Soviet resolution rejected "laughter for laughter's sake"?

Tags: soviet-union

George Counts ([1949](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20331788)):

> During the past two and one-half years the Central Committee has issued a series of "ideological resolutions" ... These resolutions not only reject "art for art's sake" and "science for science's sake," but also "laughter for laughter's sake."

Which Soviet resolution rejected "laughter for laughter's sake"?

Comment: Most likely, it is a garbled version of the 1946 resolution of the Central Committee of the Communist Party, regarding journals "Zvezda" and "Leningrad" (the part of the resolution regarding Zoshchenko). The full text can be found [here](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B1%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%A6%D0%9A_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%9F(%D0%B1)_%D0%BE%D1%82_14.08.1946_%E2%84%96_274). While garbled, the quote correctly reflects the essence of the document.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Where in that resolution is there anything about rejecting "laughter for laughter's sake"?

Comment: I said "garbled." Are you familiar with Zoshchenko's works?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: "Garbled" would be if the resolution said for example, "We reject gratuitous humor," and Counts then "garbled" it by claiming that the resolution rejected "laughter for laughter's sake". The resolution says absolutely nothing close to rejecting "laughter for laughter's sake". But I suppose since you are an expert on and thoroughly "familiar with Zoshchenko's works" (which no I am not), that qualifies you to claim otherwise.